# Can I hide a stash in git?

Tags: git, git-stash

Is it possible to hide a stash in git?

Basically, there's a stash that I'm 95% sure I won't need. I'd like to be able to not show it when I do a normal `git stash list`, but if I decide I do need it after all, I'd like to be able to pass some sort of `--show-everything` option to `git stash list` and find it.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to hide it. However you could move the stash to a new branch.

Comment: maybe like http://stackoverflow.com/a/25173231 or turn it into a .patch file stored somewhere else and then drop the stash

Comment: @NayukiMinase Is it possible to only show stashes for a given branch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526355/is-git-stash-branch-specific-or-for-the-whole-repository Look here, yes it is possible

Comment: @m.aibin which post on that page answers my question?

Comment: If you want the behavior to be per-branch, you can just make a commit (or multiple commits) on the branch. You can always "unmake" the commit(s) later (e.g., with git reset, either --soft or --mixed; see the git reset documentation; or with git rebase -i to keep only the eventual "real" commit(s) while discarding the temporaries).

Comment: This is a perfect use case for creating a branch, and not at all what stash is designed for.