# Hide but still save a branch with GIT?

Tags: git

I have a large number of branches which is getting a bit confusing to work with. Sometimes I dont want to delete the branch completely but I wont be working on it for a while. Ive adopted a convention of prefixing branches with _ when that is the case.

So if i start out with:

```
branch1
branch2
branch3
```

When Im done with branch1 but want to save a backup of it just incase then ill rename to:

```
_branch1
branch2
branch3
```

This worked well for a while but my workspace is getting a bit cluttered now. Is there anyway of saving a branch somewhere so it can be recovered, but so that its not in the normal workspace (as if its been deleted)?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169440/remove-hide-git-branches-without-deleting-commit-histories

Comment: What do you mean by _"my workspace is getting a big cluttered now"_? Do you just mean that `git branch` shows too much stuff you don't want to see all the time, such as your backup branches which begin with `_`?

Comment: If that's what you mean, here's my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66574807/4561887.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preserve your old branches in a separate repository.

That is, if you're working in `$HOME/myproject`, clone your repository:

```
cd $HOME
git clone myproject myproject_archive
```

Now, set up the `_archive` repository as a remote on your primary
repository:

```
cd myproject
git remote add archive ../myproject_archive
```

Now delete all the "old" branches in `myproject`:

```
git branch -D _branch1
etc...
```

And you're all set!  Your branches continue to exist in the
`myproject_archive` repository, and you can now trivially archive new
branches:

```
git branch -m branch2 _branch2
git push _branch2 archive
git branch -D branch2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use tags for many of the same sorts of things as branches:

```
git tag saved_branch1 branch1
git branch -D branch1
```

And, to recover the branch:

```
git branch branch1 saved_branch1
git checkout branch1
```

The catch is that tags can accidentally get pushed upstream, so you have to be careful to avoid that:

```
git push --tags         ;# Don't do this!
git push --follow-tags  ;# This will only push annotated tags on some commits
```

Since the tag command I showed above does **not** create *annotated* tags (it creates *lightweight* tags) those will not be pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Your [default refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#CRTB) is:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Make sure you have push all your branches, and then clone your repo again, but this time [only the `master` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930421/6309)

```
git clone -b master --single-branch git://sub.domain.com/repo.git
```

Then add the few branches you want to work on:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch refs/heads/my_name/branch1:refs/remotes/origin/branch1
git config --add remote.origin.fetch refs/heads/my_name/branch2:refs/remotes/origin/branch2
git fetch
```

Then start working on one of the few branches you have fetched:

```
git checkout -b branch1 origin/branch1
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the question (emphasis added):

> This worked well for a while but **my workspace is getting a bit cluttered now**. Is there anyway of saving a branch somewhere so it can be recovered, **but so that its not in the normal workspace** (as if its been deleted)?

What do you mean by *"my workspace is getting a big cluttered now"*? Do you just mean that `git branch` shows too much stuff you don't want to see all the time, such as your backup branches which begin with `_`?

If that's the case, I don't like the other solutions. The cleanest, simplest, and least storage-intensive solution by far I think is to just write your own version of `git branch`, called `git branch_` which wraps around the regular `git branch` but doesn't show your backup branches beginning with `_`.

Here's how to do that:

1. Create `git-branch_` in `~/bin`:

   ```bash
   mkdir -p ~/bin
   gedit ~/bin/git-branch_
   ```
2. Now put this into it

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   # Ignore (don't print with `git branch_`) branch names which begin with 
   # these prefix strings
   PREFIX1="z-"
   PREFIX2="_"

   git branch --color=always "$@" \
   | grep --color=never -v "^  $PREFIX1" \
   | grep --color=never -v "^  $PREFIX2"
   ```
3. Now close and re-open your terminal, and/or log out and log back in if this is the first time creating and using the `~/bin` directory (so that Ubuntu can auto-add the `~/bin` dir to your path via your `~/.profile` file). Then run the following:

   ```bash
   # 1. show ALL branches
   git branch
   # 2. show all branches EXCEPT those whose names begin with `z-` or `_`. 
   git branch_
   ```

That's it! Note that I like to prefix my backup branch names with `z-bak/some_name`, hence why I've also excluded branch names which begin with `z-`.

Since `git branch_` is a wrapper around `git branch`, and passes all arguments to it with `"$@"`, you can use ANY and all parameters/options to `git branch_` as you can to the regular `git branch`.

Example: these commands are the same:

```bash
git branch -h
git branch_ -h
```

Get this `git branch_` script in my repo here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/git-branch_.sh. See the comments inside of it as well.