# Git - From a server side hook, is it possible to control which branches a client can fetch

Tags: git

I have some automation occurring that requires the creation of extra branches, and I don't want the client to fetch these remote branches to his/her local repo. Is this possible with the use of a server side hook?

Comment: I can't find any suitable hook of the kind *pre-fetch* but I'm not an expert on Git. Would use [non-branch ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169440/remove-hide-git-branches-without-deleting-commit-histories) be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `git` has a `pre-fetch` `hook` nor it supports branch level permissions.

However you could use tools like [Gitolite](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-8.html) to manage branch level permissions and prevent internal branches from being pulled.